# insertRule does not insert style element

Tags: javascript, stylesheet

I'm trying to add a new style element into the HTML. I am currently using the code snippets from this blog post http://davidwalsh.name/add-rules-stylesheets

When it runs in codepen http://codepen.io/angelathewebdev/pen/vEjNvj?editors=101, I can't see the styles. There is a `style` element injected, but the style rules are not injected. There is no error thrown either.

When I obtain the stylesheet object, I don't see the `insertRule` or `addRule` property.

```js
 function addCSSRule(sheet, selector, rules, index) {
     if("insertRule" in sheet) {
         sheet.insertRule(selector + "{" + rules + "}", index);
     } else if("addRule" in sheet) {
         sheet.addRule(selector, rules, index);
     }
 }

 var style = document.createElement('style');

 // WebKit hack :(
 style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(''));

 // Add the <style> element to the page
 document.head.appendChild(style);

 // Stylesheet Rules
 addCSSRule(style.sheet, '.red', "background: red;", 1);
```

```html
<div class="red" style="width: 50px; height: 50px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of  `index` which you are passing is out of bound.

For `insertRule` you need not pass index.

```
 if("insertRule" in sheet) {
        sheet.insertRule(selector + "{" + rules + "}");
```

Else pass `0`

```
addCSSRule(style.sheet, '.red', "background: red;", 0);
```

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JowgOV)**

```js
 function addCSSRule(sheet, selector, rules, index) {
     if("insertRule" in sheet) {
         sheet.insertRule(selector + "{" + rules + "}", index);
     } else if("addRule" in sheet) {
         sheet.addRule(selector, rules, index);
     }
 }

 var style = document.createElement('style');

 // WebKit hack :(
 style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(''));

 // Add the <style> element to the page
 document.head.appendChild(style);

 // Stylesheet Rules
 addCSSRule(style.sheet, '.red', "background: red;", 0);
```

```html
<div class="red" style="width: 50px; height: 50px;"></div>
```

Comment: But the generated `<style>` element is still empty. Why is it empty?

Comment: @trusktr The sheet property with the inserted rules shows up in Developer Tools in Chrome when inspecting the style element: Elements - Properties tab.

Comment: @gabore Thanks. :) I would've thought it would update the style's CSS text content, but I guess the performance cost would not be ideal. But it means if one piece of code relies on text content, and another piece of code doesn't then they can be out of sync and there could be a bug.

Answer (score -1):

As per the updated documentation of *insertRule()*, it is now required to pass the *index* parameter formally. You cannot leave it.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/insertRule

Comment: _index_ is not required. The MDN link above shows the second param of insertRule as optional: `stylesheet.insertRule(rule [, index])`